# Comment on traduire les pronoms neutres singuliers anglais «they/them» pour les personnes non binaires ?

Tags: genre-biologique

Je voudrais faire référence à un individu qui, en anglais, s'identifie comme « *non-binary* » et pour qui on utilise les pronoms « *they/them* » en lieu que « *he* » ou « *she* ».  Comment, en français, peut-on respecter l'identité sexuelle de cet individu en respectant les règles de la langue ?

Answer (score 2):

Il n'existe pas de pronom spécifique non genré en français<sup>1</sup>.

Il existe un pronom neutre, ***on***, mais il n'est pas forcément facile de trouver une tournure adaptée suivant ce que l'on souhaite dire. Ce pourra être par exemple :

> **On** vous attend à l'accueil.

Il reste la solution d'utiliser *personne*, qui est grammaticalement féminin mais peut désigner des personnes de n'importe quel sexe :

> **La personne** vous attend à l'accueil.

Contrairement à l'anglais qui accorde les possessif avec le ou la propriétaire (***his** car* ou ***her** car*), le français accorde avec ce qui est possédé (**sa** voiture), donc le problème ne se pose pas dans ce cas.

Le pronom ***lui*** est lui aussi non genré quand il est utilisé comme complément par exemple dans "je **lui** parle" (*I talk to **her*** / *I talk to **him***).

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>On peut quand même citer le pronom [iel](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/iels) (mélange de *il* et de *elle*) mais, contrairement au *they/them* anglais, son utilisation est extrêmement rare et la plupart des francophones ne le connaissent pas.</sub>

Comment: Pourvu qu'*iel* ne tombe pas dans les filets du DSM-V qui se réfère au *on* conceptuel, alors que c'est l'être qui n'a pas de nom, sur lequel *on* n'a pas posé de diagnostic ou d'étiquette qui est à l'accueil :-) — *iel francophone monolingue (ou presque)* qui connaissait pas ce nouveau jargon promis à un bel avenir ! — Petit piège : « ***La personne*** vous attend à l'accueil. » contraire de « ***Personne*** vous attend à l'accueil. », même si ***les gens*** (des *personnes* anonymes !) qui parlent bien diraient … ***ne** vous attend* …

Comment: autant je commence à m'habituer au "they" singulier en anglais, autant j'ai encore beaucoup de mal avec le "iel". D'autant que ca doit souvent se combiner avec l'écriture inclusive quoi qu'il en soit...

Comment: @LaurentS.… **e·i·le[s]** si j'ai bien compris le manuel de https://www.motscles.net/ecriture-inclusive ?