# Quels adjectifs devrais-je utiliser avec le neutre « iel »

Tags: grammaire, accord, genre, lexique

[Cette question n'a rien à voir avec votre rapport personnel concernant l'usage de « iel ». Je pars du principe que c'est déjà un mot, et donc, dans le lexique français. C’est-à-dire: je n'ai pas envie d'entrer dans le débat politique, mais j'ai plutôt besoin d'en parler d'un point de vue grammatical.]

J'ai écouté un podcast hier à propos du nouveau (en quelque sorte) pronom neutre, « iel », pour ceux qui s'identifient comme ni homme ni femme. Ils en ont beaucoup parlé, mais pas de réponse claire de ce que je pouvais comprendre n'est sortie de ce débat, donc je pose la question ici: quand nous nous adressons à quelqu'un ou parlons de quelqu'un en utilisant ce pronom, devrons-nous utiliser la forme masculine ou féminine d'un adjectif ? Ou, peut-être qu'il n'y a pas de règle en ce moment, et devrons-nous plutôt leur (?) demander ce qu'iel préfère ?

**Exemple**:

> iel est beau

ou

> iel est belle

si nous ne savons pas ce qui est souhaité, devrons-nous choisir une valeur par défaut ?

Je suppose que je pourrais poser la question également pour l'accord du participe passé, etc.

Merci.

Comment: Le down-voter pourrait-il expliquer ses raisons ? Je crois avoir posé la question de façon correcte mais s'il y a quelque chose de changer pour la prochaine fois, j'aimerais bien savoir.

Comment: La question est parfaitement bien posée à mon humble avis. Et de plus dans un très bon  français (même avant les corrections de@jlliagre). Et en plus l'avertissement est parfaitement clair.

Comment: Oui, l'introduction de *iel* dans le Robert en ligne a déclenché des réactions irrationnelles de personnes, parfois haut placées, qui ne comprennent pas qu'un dictionnaire est là pour donner la liste des mots utilisés, pas pour définir ou imposer ceux qui peuvent ou ne peuvent pas l'être.

Comment: Excellente question !

Comment: À voir aussi : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45203/comment-on-traduire-les-pronoms-neutres-singuliers-anglais-they-them-pour-les/45205#45205

Comment: On pourrait dire, c'est une belle personne.

Comment: @Dimitris Quand on dit de quelqu'un que c'est « une belle personne » on ne parle pas de son apparence physique mais de ses qualités morales. Je ne crois pas que ce soit ce que l'OP voulait dire, du moins quand on dit de quelqu'un « il est beau », « elle est belle » ça s'applique uniquement à son apparence physique.

Comment: Si on fait une **phrase**, ne faut-t-il pas utiliser une/des majuscule(s)?? **Il est beau. Elle est belle." Iel est beau/belle. indépendamment du pronom??

Comment: @Lambie Absolument, et c'est ce que j'ai d'abord fait dans ma réponse, mais le *i* majuscule étant à peu près indiscernable du *L* minuscule et le pronom *iel* étant aujourd'hui rarissime, je suis revenu aux minuscules pour que ce soit clair, sinon, on croit qu'il est écrit *LEL* tout en minuscules. C'est un problème de police de caractères.

Comment: @jlliagre D'accord, je comprends.

Comment: Je viens de signaler cet article de the conversation : 
[*« Iel » : itinéraire d’une polémique*](https://theconversation.com/iel-itineraire-dune-polemique-172338) sur le chat. Comme je en sais pas si tu y vas....

Comment: @None Super - merci !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On peut se limiter aux adjectifs épicènes ou qui s'écrivent de manière similaire au masculin et au féminin, voire en créer de nouveaux.

> iel est magnifique.
> iel est joli·e<sup>1</sup>.
> iel est pas moche...
> iel est [belleau](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/belleau)
> iel est beauté (© @Personne)

C'est la même chose pour le participe passé:

> iel est parti·e.

<sup>1</sup> J'utilise a dessein le point médian ici, mais comme l'a indiqué None, son utilisation introduit de sérieuses difficultés dans la langue, et en particulier la rend à peu près imprononçable quand les masculins et féminins sont incompatibles (ex: lecteur·rice·s).

Comment: Bonne idée - simple et claire. Diriez-vous que c'est courant à faire, à présent ?

Comment: On parle beaucoup plus du pronom *iel* en ce moment qu'on ne l'utilise vraiment dans la vie courante. Si quelqu'un me demande qu'on utilise *iel*, c'est sûrement l'approche que j'aurais mais ça ne m'est pas encore arrivé.

Comment: @DerekAllums L'utilisation du point median est très controversée car discriminant vis à vis des handicapés.  [Par exemple](https://www.ffdys.com/actualites/ecriture-inclusive-et-dyslexie-lavis-de-la-ffdys.htm). Sujet hautement politique et polémique.

Comment: @None — Puisqu'un mot est neutre, l'article défini le genre, et l'adjectif est invariable puisqu'il définit une qualité : « La/Le/iel maître est adroit/sensible » « [Las (absence bizarre non ?]/Les/iels maître [pourrait aussi être invariable s'il s'agit d'une même maîtrise, avec 's' s'il s'agit de personnes exerçant des métiers/arts différents] sont adroit/sensible » Un être (masculin/féminin/neutre), une qualité universelle qui ramène à l'essentiel …

Comment: … on n'est pas loin de notre langage originel « Les chevals ont courri beaucoup vite » n'en déplaise au vieux paternalisme dominant et à ses codes pervers et manipulateurs :-)

Comment: @Personne J'ai voulu ajouter *iel est bello* puis j'ai trouvé que *belleau* existait déjà :-)

Comment: *iel est beauté* simplifierait bien la vie ! Ou alors périphrase : *iel a la beauté d'iel chat*, sinon on reste piégé par L'AAAcaKdémie franchouillarde :-[ — À la règle d'Albert Camus : sujet, verbe, complément s'ajoute alors : tout est neutre et invariable s'il ne signifie des êtres/objets/états différents, le sujet décide du genre. Cela n'empêcherait pas  d'être glamour puisque *toi = iel* (pas plus genré)

Comment: … et après tout « Mignon allons voir si la rose … » peut convenir à tout le monde et rester sans genre jusqu'à la fin du poème, sans qu'il soit obligé (ou non) de lui fournir un genre  pour plaire aux conventions sociales.